# Adding a variable interval to a variable timestamp

Tags: php, postgresql

Ok, first of all I have very little clue how to use php, and only a slightly better understanding of sql. So if anything I do appears really, really stupid, please bear with me.

Given a user input of a date, a time and a time interval, I need to get two timestamps without timezones - a starting time, and an endtime.
e.g.

```
function myfunction($startdate, $starttime, $numhours){

$start = $startdate.' '.$starttime;
//I know this works for a timestamp because I have used this value in other sql statements and have been returned the correct results

$handler = $connection->prepare("SELECT TIMESTAMP :start + INTERVAL :numhours ' HOURS'");
$handler->bindParam(':start', $start);        
$handler->bindParam(':numhours', $numhours);
$handler->execute(); 
$end = $handler->fetchAll();
```

This just gets me the following error:

```
Submitting booking.SQLSTATE[42601]: Syntax error: 7 ERROR: syntax error at or near "$1" LINE 1: SELECT TIMESTAMP $1 + INTERVAL $2 ' HOURS'
```

I haven't been able to find anything that really tells me what I'm doing wrong here (which is probably a lot). Help is appreciated.

EDIT: I'm using `postgreSQL`, through `pgAdmin III

EDIT: $start should have the form 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS'

Comment: what is in `$start` and `$numhours`?

Comment: $start is meant to be a string of the form 'YYYY-MM-DD HH-MM-SS', which I've found works when searching for a timestamp in sql. $numhours is just an integer

Comment: Your interval literal has a syntax error too, use `INTERVAL '3 hours'` or `INTERVAL '3' HOUR` (instead of `INTERVAL '3' ' HOURS'`)

Comment: Ok, but there's still an issue with the first variable (:start) which I can't work out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is, you use the [literal notation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-CONSTANTS-GENERIC) with values (parameters) and not with constants.

The literal notation only accepts contants, like:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMP '2014-05-25 14:29:59' + INTERVAL 3 HOUR;
```

It cannot accept values (expressions) other than constants (and bound parameters are not constants.):

```
-- this will throw a syntax error
SELECT TIMESTAMP CONCAT('2014-05-25', ' ', '14:29:59');
```

You can use the `CAST` form over the literal notation here:

```
$handler = $connection->prepare('SELECT CAST(:start AS TIMESTAMP) + ' .
                                'CAST(:numhours || \' hours\' AS INTERVAL)');
$handler->bindParam(':start', $start);        
$handler->bindParam(':numhours', $numhours);
$handler->execute();
```

**EDIT**: or, you can use [`PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.constants.php#pdo.constants.attr-emulate-prepares) to use real literals inside your query, but I believe postgres' own prepare functionality is better a choice.

Comment: Could you explain what is happening in the second half of that? When you're casting :numhours.

Comment: @user3464331 `||` is the text concatenation operator in postgres. `CAST` hasn't got the option to specify only the `HOUR` part of the `INTERVAL`, so you need to feed it with `'3 hours'` or `'03:00:00'` (or anything the interval accepts) http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-INTERVAL-INPUT

Comment: Well sweet! Thanks for that, it works. I thought the bindParam put the variable in as a sort of string, but evidently I was mistaken.